# Return the same type as a lambda expression passed as argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I want to create a function that accepts both function pointers and lambda expressions. The return type of the function should be the same as the return type of the function pointer/lambda expression.

The following is a minimal example of a function that works as intended but for function pointers only. Can I use templates to accept lambda expressions as well?

```
template <typename R>
R foo(R (*func)())
{
    return func();
}
```

The following works for both function pointers and lambda expressions but only accepts `bool`.

```
bool foo(std::function<bool()> func)
{
    return func();
}

bool a = foo( [](){ return true; } );
```

I tried to make it generic using templates but I get a compiler error when it's called (no matching function)

```
template <typename R>
R foo(std::function<R()> func)
{
    return func();
}

bool a = foo( [](){ return true; } );
```

Comment: Lambdas with no capture can convert to function-pointers

Comment: @sp2danny: True, but that presupposes that you have a context for that conversion. The first problem here is that you don't know the function pointer type to which it would convert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use deduced return type:

```
template <typename F>
auto foo(F f) -> decltype(f())
{
    return f();
}
```

And if `F` takes some arguments :

```
template <typename F, typename ... Args>
auto foo(F f, Args&&...args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can this solution be expanded to support passing a parameter to f? 

E.g. `R foo(R (*f)(T), T x) { return f(x); }`

Comment: @SamOlesen: Yes, solution can be extended to support args : see edit.

Comment: What if "f" takes a parameter which is not listed in a "foo" params list?

Comment: @ARA1307: the `decltype` usage here allows SFINAE, overload `foo` with invalid (or missing) argument would not participate. You will so have error as expected.

Answer (score 4):

That's a job for `decltype` :

```
template <typename F>
auto foo(F f) -> decltype(f()) 
{
}
```